# Is it possible to update a view that was created from a strongly typed model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a View based on a strongly typed model class in my MVC4 project and it all worked well. However I had to add a bunch of fields to the Model class and now I want the View to reflect that. Originally all the fields were created automatically for me when I selected the strogly typed class.

I know I could *manually* go and add the new HTML helper fields, but I was wondering if there was some way to 'Update' the View from it's bound model class (i.e. some link in the IDE like "Refresh View" or something").

I also know I could delete the current View and have it re-created but I was wondering if it was possible with a bit less brute force in case I had made unrelated customizations that I didn't want wiped out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use EditorForModel() or DisplayForModel() in your view, they will update for free when you make changes to your model.

Here's the link to [Brad Wilson's blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) that I've found super useful.  It's written for MVC2, but as far as I know, everything still applies in MVC3.

Also, a particular data annotation that is really handy when using EditorForModel() is:

```
[ScaffoldColumns(false)] //for properties that you don't want to display, but still need their values to post to the server(like ID's and such)
```

Comment: The IDE created `EditorFor` helpers and not `EditorForModel` so would I have to change everything?

Comment: @atconway  A single EditorForModel() will effectively replace all of the Editorfor(x => x. whatever) statements.  The framework will create appropriate inputs for each property in your model.

Comment: That's right I did read about that in my MVC book. Downsides? What if I need to intervene on a particular controls look or behavior? Are all of the data annotations enough to handle variances?

Comment: @atconway Data annotations can handle a very large set of variances, but if you want, you can easily write a custom template for the editor and do pretty much whatever you want with it.  I'll add a link to a great blog post by Brad Wilson on the subject.

Comment: Yep it was the book he co-authored that I read and was quite useful. Ok so this is a fantastic *alternative solution* but do you concur with the other comments that there is no 'IDE refresh' style option to make this happen?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no 'refresh' type of option for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this. What you could do is create a new view and then use a diff tool to compare the two files and merge the changes. If you added some custom code to your file then you wouldn't lose any of that.